# Htaccess redirect https to another https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have just bought the .com extension for our domain and we are using ssl certificates on both of them:

```
https://www.domain.net
https://www.domain.com
```

Now we would like to use the .com extension **only** and redirect our users from the old domain to the new one using the htaccess file:

```
http[s]://domain.net -------|
http[s]://www.domain.net ---|---> https://www.domain.com
http[s]://domain.com -------|
```

I am not very familiar with htaccess so I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http[s]?://(www\.)?domain\.com(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http[s]?://www.domain.com/? [R,L]
```

That obviously doesn't work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot match scheme `http://` in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It works but it's adding a trailing slash. ``https://domain.net`` redirects to ``https://www.domain.com//``. It's probably related to Magento, right?

Comment: Actually `/` before `%{REQUEST_URI}` wasn't needed. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect! I've just changed the 302 for a 301 for seo purposes.

Comment: `connection is not secure` issue cannot be resolved by rewrite rules because SSL handshake with Apache happens before `mod_rewrite` module is inoked.

Comment: This was great for me and I also changed from 302 to 301. Thanks